# How to let Selenium run while waiting for user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I want to let selenium webdriver run while waiting for user input.

Suppose

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver

def input_data():
    how_much = input('How many?')
    return how_much    

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://www.example.com')

example_text = input_data()
driver.find_element_by_id('example_id').send_keys(example_text)
```

The idea is while selenium.webdriver still loading the page (http://www.example.com), I can input something using `input_data()`. 
By the time selenium webdriver finish loading the page, I can use the `input_data()` return value to `send_keys` to the website form (`driver.find_element_by_id('example_id').send_keys(example_text)`)

My place got slow internet connection so I think while waiting for page to loading, I ask for user input.

Is this possible? If so how can I code this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Python, but in order to do things simultaneously, you should check [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html).

Comment: This is called asynchronous programming and too broad a topic to explain in a single answer on SO.

Comment: Ok, i will take look at it. So far threading and queue suppose to be something im looking for.